# Deploy Web Services like Web App or like a Servlet

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, web-applications, jax-ws

I'm deploying with Tomcat some WebServices (jax-ws) and I have a question about which could be the best way to do it.

I have a project with 8 classes defined as WebService like this:

```
@WebService(name = "FirstWS")
public class FirstWebService extends WebServiceBase{......
```

And I have just one `web.xml` in the project.

Which is the best way to deploy it thinking about balancing and stability? Each one like a WebApp or like a Servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balancing and stability will come down to the quality of your code. If all is well, there is no particular reason to split everything up into individual web applications.

The choice of deployment has much more to do with your architecture and internal requirements. You haven't provided any details about what that architecture is or what other requirements exist, so nobody can really give you any good advice.

Comment: That WebServices make reads and writes to Cassandra (bussiness model) and MongoDb (file storage) to give suport to a mobile app. I'd like to grow as I need, thinking in thousands of users. I'm new about deployment, but if a webapplication falls down all services will be broken, isn't? If i've separed in different webapps, if one is down the others will continue serving.

Comment: "Falls down" is a matter of perspective. If the JVM suffers OOME or something, then everything is probably ruined. If a single request encounters an exception, it doesn't matter to anyone else. If the database is unavailable, it doesn't matter what your deployment model is. It's pretty rare to fatally break a specific web application and still have the JVM (and other applications running on it) stay running properly. If you are concerned, go with a one-app-per-JVM deployment model.